# First argument to get_object_or_404() must be a Modelt, not 'function'

Tags: python, django

First argument to get_object_or_404() must be a Model, Manager, or QuerySet, not 'function'.

I'm trying to show tablet details based on the tablet in the database but it keeps getting this ValueError. Can anyone help me find out what I am doing wrong?

this is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import PharmaceuticalCapsules, PharmaceuticalSuspension, 
PharmaceuticalPowder, PharmaceuticalSyrup, \
PharmaceuticalTablet


def alltablet(request):
tablet = PharmaceuticalTablet.objects
return render(request, 'tablets.html', {'tablet': tablet})


def tabdetail(request, tab_id):
tabdetail = get_object_or_404(alltablet, pk=tab_id)
return render(request, 'tab_detail.html', {'tablet': tabdetail})
```

this is my models.py

```
from typing import re
from django.db import models

class PharmaceuticalTablet(models.Model):
tab_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
tab_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image/', blank=True, null=True)
tab_dose_strength = models.CharField(max_length=100)
tab_pack = models.CharField(max_length=100)
tab_form = models.CharField(max_length=200)
tab_dose = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Direction By Physician')
tab_storage = models.CharField(max_length=100)
tab_usage = models.CharField(max_length=100)
tab_brandname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
tab_composition = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def __str__(self):
    return self.tab_name
```

browser shows

```
ValueErrorat /tablet/1/
First argument to get_object_or_404() must be a Model, Manager, or QuerySet, not 'function'.
Request Method:
GET 
Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/tablet/1/ 

Django Version:
v2.2.1 

Exception Type:
ValueError 

Exception Value:
First argument to get_object_or_404() must be a Model, Manager, or QuerySet, not 'function'.
```

Comment: Exactly what the error message shows. You are trying to pass alltablet, which is a function. Do you want to see details of a PharmaceuticalTablet? If so then change tabdetail to `tabdetail = get_object_or_404(PharmaceuticalTable, pk=tab_id)` You can read more here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial03/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tabdetail = get_object_or_404(PharmaceuticalTablet, pk=tab_id)

make that change. You want to identify the modal, not a function.

Answer (score 3):

Like the error shows, you are trying to pass to `get_object_or_404(...)` a function instead of a queryset or a Model. I think you want to use `PharmaceuticalTablet.objects.all()` unless you wish to filter it before.

```
def alltablet(request):
    tablet = PharmaceuticalTablet.objects
    return render(request, 'tablets.html', {'tablet': tablet})


def tabdetail(request, tab_id):
    tabdetail = get_object_or_404(PharmaceuticalTablet.objects.all(), pk=tab_id)
    return render(request, 'tab_detail.html', {'tablet': tabdetail})
```